# Compass - CSS files caching

Tags: compass-sass

Compass appends a unique ID to my sprites everytime a new image appears in the Compass images folder. Is the same behavior available with the CSS files ? So my CSS file is named mystyle-12343321.css instead of mystyle.css

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As detailed by Scott Davis (Compass core team dev), in this [Compass Github Issue](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/1374) (opened by myself) :

> It's not a cache buster in the sense of the web it's a uniqueness  hash. It's how compass tracks changes to the sprite file so that we know if it needs to be recompiled

So the answer is no, as Compass does not support cache busting.